# How can I navigate to a url programmatically with a correct referer header?

Tags: javascript, apache-flex

I have a flex application that uses the actionscript navigateToURL function to go to another system. However, a third party app that needs to be integrated checks for valid links by looking at the HTTP referer header, and it seems like that header is blank when using a navigateToURL call.

Is there a way in actionscript or javascript to programatically generate a url and go to it with a correct referer header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aaah the referer header. I had a lot of frustration from this.

Long story short, in Flex+AIR, no matter what you do (ex: manually change headers) the referer will ALWAYS be overwritten by the framework. I never actually tried it inside a browser (i.e. : not in AIR) so I can't confirm it behaves the same. You can try for yourself if you want by adding a new header to an URLRequest object like this :

```
var request:URLRequest;
request.requestHeaders.push(new URLRequestHeader("referer", "myReferer.com");
```

Here's a bunch of interesting links confirming what I'm saying. I suggest you vote for the idea on Adobe Labs Ideas and comment on the bug on Adobe bugbase

Post on Adobe Forums : [HtmlLoader and "Referer" request header](http://forums.adobe.com/message/3841814#3841814)

Adobe Labs Ideas : [Don't set default referer in HTML Header](http://ideas.adobe.com/ct/ct_a_view_idea.bix?c=9D564F43-979A-4E35-AA21-85A61B6AB8DE&idea_id=CA6C107B-CE93-4DAF-82EA-503C4DB2B1F8)

Bug in Adobe bugbase : [Default HTTP request referrer (referer header field) app://[app_name].swf causes denied access by some websites](https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=2945647)

Question on the matter on SO : [Intercepting network calls to force Html header referer to null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083560/intercepting-network-calls-to-force-html-header-referer-to-null)